# Two Steps to set Session as Logged In

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a strange problem that does not set the user as logged in to the SESSION until a second click (although they are logged in)

So, I have a login dropdown that looks like this:

[image]

I send the user to the ACCOUNT-SELECTOR. PHP to determine the approprirate validation based on a business or individual account:

```
if (isset($_POST['loginAccountType']) && $_POST['loginAccountType'] == 'individual') {       
     include('ind_login.php');;
} elseif (isset($_POST['loginAccountType']) && $_POST['loginAccountType'] == 'business') {
     include('bus_login.php');
} else {
     include('error_login.php');
}
```

I have `session_start();` on my account-selector.php page as well as my `ind_login.php` page.  And, both are located at the very top of the page (before anything else).

Once I log in, this is my view:

[image]

As you can see, I am able to set and return the `$_SESSION['Ind_ID']` on the `ind_login.php` page and VIEW YOUR PROFILE works (which is linked to the SESSION ID).

However, we still see a LOG IN button on the navigation when the code says this button should be set to display:none:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Ind_ID'])) {
     $accIndStyle = "visibility: visible;"; 
} else {
     $accIndStyle = "display:none;";
}
```

I know this is the correct code as the button does become display: none for other buttons.  However, if I log in a second time, or go to a different page with the session(start), the site will read the `$_SESSION['Ind_ID']` as set and hide the Login button and replace it with a logout button.

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Put your session_start() on the top of your index.php file (That file which includes the others.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; unfortunately, putting the session_start() on the top of the file that includes both (my header file) does not change the situation.  It must be one silly mistake I'm making.

Comment: Check if the `$_SESSION["Ind_ID"]` has a value after the `session_start()` in the index.php (`print_r($_SESSION)`). If it is defined, the var will be somewhere cleared. You can also make the logged-in status fixed with an `if ($_SESSION["Ind_ID"]) define("login", true); else define("login", false);` on the top of your main php file.

Answer (score 0):

seem like your page needs to be refreshed, or just throw an ajax call in there to update the button value according to session.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; unfortunately, when I refresh the page, it creates an error as the page can't retrieve the values from the input as when I refresh the page (there are no values coming in from the input).  It must be one silly mistake I'm making.

Comment: You were right.  I just need to refresh the header page (the page with the login form + navigation menu when the log in button is pressed.

Jst don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Send an ajax request to a back end script, if the session is ok, update the content:)